Optimal common substring elimination
The problem:
You are given a list of strings as an input. You may perform any number of "token substitution" operations. A token substitution is performed by: removing any substring, replacing instances with a new token, and adding that substring to the list. The output of the algorithm is the modified list.
For example, for the input ["abc", "abc", "abcdebcde"], you could replace all instances of "abc" with "A". This leads to the final output of ["A", "A", "Adebcde", "abc"].
The goal is to find the optimal output that:

Minimizes the sum of the lengths of the output strings
As a tiebreaker, minimizes the number of new tokens.

The output above has a length sum of 12 and 1 new token.
The main challenge is to decide which substrings to tokenize. Tokenizing substrings of size 1 or that only occur once obviously does not help. Ignoring those, the above example has the following repeated substrings of length >= 2:



String
Count




ab
3


abc
3


bc
4


bcd
2


bcde
2


cd
2


cde
2


de
2



Some obvious algorithms are "Pick the most common substring" and "Pick the largest substring". Those both perform worse than choosing "abc" -> "A" for the example input.
Another algorithm is to greedily choose the substring that reduces the length sum the most, and repeat until the string cannot be shortened any more.
Let l be the length of the substring and let c be the count. Tokenizing a substring removes l*c characters, adds c replacement characters and adds another string of length l, leaving to a total "score" of l*n - (l+n). This correctly chooses "abc", the optimal choice for the example.
However, I'm having trouble convincing myself this is always optimal. My concern is that when a substring is removed, any overlapping substrings can no longer be removed. That is, if I remove "ab" from "abc", then I can no longer remove "bc". So if the 2nd and 3rd highest scoring both overlap with the 1st highest score but not with eachother, perhaps it would be optimal to choose the 2nd and 3rd rather than the 1st. Hopefully that makes sense.
This seems related to dictionary compression techniques, but I'm not sure it's quite the same.
So, what is the optimal algorithm? And is there a proof for it?
A slight variation on the problem that would be interesting to see as well:
Instead of minimizing the number of new tokens as a tiebreaker, each new token adds a fixed cost C to length sum. That or any similar problem would be interesting to see a solution for.

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequitur_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_induction

Is going from [abc abc abcdebcde] via [aA aA aAdeAde bc] and [B B aAdeAde bc aA] to [B B aCC bc aA Ade] permissible? (Storer, Szymanski CPM (?))

@greybeard Yes, that transformation is allowed. Not applying a substitution like you did for aA on that third string is valid. Though of course the algorithm would have to decide when to do that.
Is your citation at the end referring to this paper? https://doi.org/10.1145/322344.322346 I'll have to read it.

@D.W. hadn't thought of it as a grammar problem. Looking into that now, it looks like I'm essentially trying to solve the Smallest Grammar Problem (or similar). Which appears to be NP-complete. I was afraid of that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_grammar_problem

I think I knew this rendition.
